# Why does the scaling exponent of a power law fit change so radically when the data is scaled by a constant?

Tags: matlab, least-squares, nonlinear-regression, power-law

Consider the following data and the code

```
% The data
x = [4 4.5 5 5.5 6 6.5];

y1 =  [0.000159334114311,0.000184477307337,0.002931979623674,...
    0.004321711975947,0.006269020390557,0.012537205790269];

y2 = [0.000160708687146,0.000186102543697,0.002956862489638,...
    0.004356837209873,0.006325918592142,0.012667035948290];

% The fit is setup
ft = fittype( 'power1' );
opts = fitoptions( ft );
opts.DiffMaxChange = 0.1;
opts.DiffMinChange = 1e-16;
opts.Display = 'Off';
opts.Lower = [0 0];
opts.MaxFunEvals = 99999;
opts.MaxIter = 99999;
opts.StartPoint = [1 10];
opts.TolFun = 1e-16;
opts.TolX = 1e-16;
opts.Upper = [Inf Inf];

% The fits are executed
[fitresult, gof] = fit( x', y1', ft)
[fitresult, gof] = fit( x', y1'/86400, ft)
[fitresult, gof] = fit( x', y2', ft)
[fitresult, gof] = fit( x', y2'/86400, ft)
```

I was trying to fit y1 vs. x and then y2 vs. x to a simple power law $y=ax^b$. Mainly I am interested in the exponent $b$. Don't care much for $a$. As I started playing with different units, converting y1 and y2 between days and seconds, I saw that for y1, the exponent stayed the same after scaling but for y2, the exponent changed significantly after scaling.

For y1, here is the output

```
fitresult = 

 General model Power1:
 fitresult(x) = a*x^b
 Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
   a =   1.465e-09  (-8.771e-09, 1.17e-08)
   b =       8.542  (4.759, 12.32)

gof = 

       sse: 4.265059892284385e-06
   rsquare: 0.960370163394534
       dfe: 4
adjrsquare: 0.950462704243167
      rmse: 0.001032601071601

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

fitresult = 

 General model Power1:
 fitresult(x) = a*x^b
 Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
   a =   1.696e-14  (-1.015e-13, 1.354e-13)
   b =       8.542  (4.759, 12.32)

gof = 

       sse: 5.713439713386793e-16
   rsquare: 0.960370163394534
       dfe: 4
adjrsquare: 0.950462704243167
      rmse: 1.195140129167579e-08
```

we see that in this case the exponent is 8.542 in both cases, identical for my purposes. But for the second data set, I get

```
fitresult = 

 General model Power1:
 fitresult(x) = a*x^b
 Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
   a =   3.472e-08  (-1.099e-07, 1.794e-07)
   b =        6.83  (4.561, 9.099)

gof = 

       sse: 2.501974567230523e-06
   rsquare: 0.977224831423532
       dfe: 4
adjrsquare: 0.971531039279415
      rmse: 7.908815599112364e-04

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

fitresult = 

 General model Power1:
 fitresult(x) = a*x^b
 Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
   a =    1.71e-14  (-1.019e-13, 1.361e-13)
   b =       8.542  (4.774, 12.31)

gof = 

       sse: 5.784659576382752e-16
   rsquare: 0.960691723661228
       dfe: 4
adjrsquare: 0.950864654576535
      rmse: 1.202565962471784e-08
```

now the exponent was 6.83 and then changed to 8.542 after changing units. Why did this happen?

The unit conversion is straightforward, just multiplication by a constant. I imagine that for a power law the exponent wouldn't depend on the scale of the data. For example, if I start with a quadratically correlated data, then multiply all of the y-coordinates by 10, the correlation will still be quadratic but the multiplicative constant will be multiplied by ten. So two questions.

1. Why does the exponent change when I scale the y-values? Should the exponent change so? Which behavior is more common? I thought scaling should make no difference so the first behavior should be more common than the second but then I don't understand why the second behavior should occur at all?
2. More importantly, what is the difference between the two data sets? Why the different behavior? Why does one change but not the other? Is there a deep mathematical reason behind it or is it easily explainable? Is it something inherent in the data itself? Thought I can't imagine what could it be. They are both so similar. Or does it have something to do with the black-box algorithm in MATLAB? Initialization and bounding parameter values doesn't make a difference. The algorithm always converges to these same values. It doesn't matter if I initialize or if I let MATLAB initialize. Is it something inherent in non-linear least squares method? I always imagined NLLSF to a power law to be robust to scaling but apparently it isn't. Very surprising I think!

Is this phenomenon well-known/studied? If someone can point me to some references as well, that would be great.

Thank you.

---

Addendum #1,

Following whuber's comment, "one has to suspect that the nonlinear fitting procedure is finding its solutions with relatively poor precision", after some careful playing around with the data (which I should have done to begin with) it turns out that the culprit was indeed low tolerance error. In my posted code,

```
[fitresult, gof] = fit( x', y1', ft)
```

should have been

```
[fitresult, gof] = fit( x', y1', ft,opts)
```

where I forgot to include opts and hence the tolerance (TolFun) was at the default 1e-6 instead of my specified 1e-16. So now MATLAB was returning answers much closer to what R is getting. Furthermore, I see that R and Mathematica seem to be automatically using the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm while MATLAB keeps using Trust-Region algorithm. When I force MATLAB to use Levenberg-Marquardt, it now spits out identical answers to R and Mathematica. Thanks everyone!

Comment: The output of the fourth example is almost the same as the second example. In particular, $b=8.542$ again. Are you absolutely sure that you ran the fourth example with `y2` and not accidently with `y1` (for example, by re-naming the variable by mistake?) You probably didn't, but it just looks a little strange that the values of `b` are exactly the same in Examples 1,2 and 4.

Comment: To fit a power law distribution with MLE, I suggest looking here (includes code): http://tuvalu.santafe.edu/~aaronc/powerlaws/

Comment: @Flounderer Well, that's why I provided the code. The output provided is from that MATLAB code. The confidence bounds on $b$ for the two cases are different, slightly yes but still different.

Comment: @Bitwise I am familiar with Clauset's work and have looked at those papers and the code a while back when I asked my previous power-law questions. From what I understand the MLE method he talks about applies to data taken from a power law distribution. I am trying to fit the data itself to a power law functional form.

Comment: @Fixed Point, yes, I thought it was probably only a faint hope, but it's good to be sure. Also, I do get different confidence intervals and values of `a` from one run to another when I fit the same model using R's `nls` function.

Comment: @Flounderer Can you please post the output of power-law fitting using NLLSF in R for the four different data? I am curious to see what happens with R? How different is it? Any info on how R's algorithm works, how initialization is done, etc. would also be interesting. I am gonna see if I can google something about how nls works in R. Thanks!

Comment: OK. I've posted the output in an answer.

Comment: It is straightforward to *prove* that scaling does not alter the correct estimates. Noting that the two estimates for `y2` are not significantly different, one has to suspect that the nonlinear fitting procedure is finding its solutions with relatively poor precision. Providing better starting values is one way to improve such behavior. Consider estimating $a$ and $b$ with a preliminary *linear* model $\log(y) = \log(a) + b\log(x)$ to obtain good starting values. This can also give a large set of diagnostics to assess other potential problems, such as a large VIF in the design matrix.

Comment: @whuber Linear fitting with a linear model to the log-log of the data gives me slope = 9.76 in all four cases and the intercepts are what you'd expect. y1 and y2 give identical intercepts. y1/86400 and y2/86400 give identical intercepts. But then when I use those to initialize the non-linear power law fit, I get the same exact results as above. There must be something weird in the MATLAB black-box. Any idea what it is or how to control/get rid of it? Thanks!

Comment: @whuber You were right about the poor precision. Please see the addendum to my question. If you would post your comment as an answer I will upvote it and accept it as an answer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what it looks like in R.

```
x <- c(4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5)
y1 <- c(0.000159334114311, 0.000184477307337, 0.002931979623674, 0.004321711975947, 
0.006269020390557, 0.012537205790269)
y2 <- c(0.000160708687146, 0.000186102543697, 0.002956862489638, 0.004356837209873, 
0.006325918592142, 0.01266703594829)

> (out1 <- nls(y1 ~ a*x^b, start=list(a=1,b=10)))
Nonlinear regression model
  model:  y1 ~ a * x^b 
   data:  parent.frame() 
        a         b 
2.880e-08 6.926e+00 
 residual sum-of-squares: 2.446e-06

Number of iterations to convergence: 31 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.326e-07 

> (out2 <- nls(y1/86400 ~ a*x^b, start=list(a=1,b=10)))
Nonlinear regression model
  model:  y1/86400 ~ a * x^b 
   data:  parent.frame() 
        a         b 
3.333e-13 6.926e+00 
 residual sum-of-squares: 3.277e-16

Number of iterations to convergence: 11 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 2.176e-07 

> (out3 <- nls(y2 ~ a*x^b, start=list(a=1,b=10)))
Nonlinear regression model
  model:  y2 ~ a * x^b 
   data:  parent.frame() 
        a         b 
2.849e-08 6.938e+00 
 residual sum-of-squares: 2.491e-06

Number of iterations to convergence: 30 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 2.456e-07 

> (out4 <- nls(y2/86400 ~ a*x^b, start=list(a=1,b=10)))
Nonlinear regression model
  model:  y2/86400 ~ a * x^b 
   data:  parent.frame() 
        a         b 
3.297e-13 6.938e+00 
 residual sum-of-squares: 3.337e-16

Number of iterations to convergence: 11 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 4.397e-07
```

plots:

```
plot(x, y1, "l")
lines(x, y2, "l", col="green")
lines(x, out1$m$fitted(), col="red")
lines(x, out3$m$fitted(), col="red")
```

[image]

Looks reasonable. I don't think `nls` produces confidence intervals by default. For a readable account of how it works, see *Modern Applied Statistics with S*, Section 8.2.

None of this answers your question, but I hope it helps.

Comment: I see that you are getting all exponents around 6.92 and 6.93. I checked in mathematica and mathemtica is identical to your R output. Now I am worried about MATLAB, what the heck is going on? Thanks for posting though.